# Subversion: Branch per Environment?

Tags: .net, svn, deployment, branching-and-merging

I am currently working on a project in .NET which consists of several logical layers and multiple front-ends. Here is a rough representation of our SVN structure:

```
trunk
---doc
---lib
---src
------console
---------console.vbproj
------domain
---------domain.vbproj
------...
------web
---------web.vbproj
---.sln
```

All of our day-to-day development occurs in trunk - this is where all developers checkout from/commit to.

I am looking for a way to cleanly and easily deploy between environments (test and production).

My thought is to create two branches, test and production, from trunk - solution and all. I am justifying this to myself for the following reasons:

1. I have complete control over which modifications flow to which environments by only merging from trunk to the test branch and from the test branch to the production branch
2. I can easily see what code is executing in each environment by simply looking at the log of the corresponding branch in Subversion

Has anyone had any experience with a solution similar to this? Are there any potential pitfalls or oversights that I am missing?

Comment: Just in case anyone is still curious, there are several blog posts concerning this approach; just Google "branch per promotion". I believe most of the material out there is just a regurgitation of what Jeff Atwood originally blogged about in October, 2007: [see here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/software-branching-and-parallel-universes.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Has anyone had any experience with a solution similar to this?

Yes :-)

> Are there any potential pitfalls or oversights that I am missing?

You will face the problem that over time the test and release branches will drift away from the development environment as you will very likely not merge every change from trunk. The developers will then work in a slightly different environment and you will waste much time by keeping the branches in sync. This is known as the [merge-mania anti-pattern](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/bradapp/acme/branching/pitfalls.html#MergeMania).

I would rather advise to create a release branch from trunk for each planned release once you got all features for it implemented. At the time you branch both are equal. Then have a team to stabilize and test on the release branch. The development goes in parallel on trunk. Once your release was polished merge the fixes back to trunk.

Repeat the procedure for each release. This way you will limit the number of merges and have the folks working on something that always is the cutting edge.

I hope these aspects help you in your decision. The link also shows many other anti-patterns. Have a read to all of them maybe you'll recognize some lessons learned and will get some hints to solve it better.

Comment: With the "branch per release" methodology, how would you go about automating deployment? For instance, using "branch per environment" I could build scripts such that each branch is compiled and deployed to it's respective environment. Then, deployment becomes as easy as merging to my desired branch and running the corresponding script.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding what you mean with environment. Usually if there is a common core you will switch (or externalize with svn:externals) the environment specific code. So there is no need for merges. If you can run scripts for performing merges then there must be something conceptually wrong in your setup. Merging is a value-adding work that cannot be automated in general. If it can be automated, there is no value adding, so it's probably only unnecessary overhead in your case.

Comment: Upvote for introducing to me the phrase "merge mania".  That led to alot of anti patterns for branching.  Thanks jdehaan.

Answer (score 2):

We're using the same layout without any issues. Make sure to use the latest svn version. Version prior to 1.5 should not be used because of missing merge tracking.

In conjunction with a bug tracking tool like jira from atlassian (I'm not sponsored) your setup gets even more transparent.